# Regex split value on the URL C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the url from one website and it is as following :

```
http://www.testwebsite.com/busqueda/(idPartner)/VINCCI/(codigoHotel)/20017/(zona)/74986/(lang)/es/(idPrm)/MBVINCCI/(idONg)/P69/(idNom)/VincciHoteles/(idListaHoteles)/Y/(dia)/7/(mes)/4/(anio)/2014/(diaHasta)/8/(mesHasta)/4/(anioHasta)/2014/(habitaciones)/1/(irListaHoteles)/Y/(adultsRoom1)/2/(childrenRoom1)/0
```

now I wish to get the 20017 position out of the URL by Regex, could you suggest me which pattern is the best to achieve it in this case?

Comment: Could you give us an example URL to work on?

Comment: Looks like it'll occur at a fixed position.  Consider splitting on a delimiter.

Comment: Yes I have the url in the above question @AlphaDelta

Comment: Any reason you want a regex? Don't you want something more readable?

Comment: @bluewonder You could try @devnull 's idea and go for `url.Replace("http://", "").split('/')[5]`

Comment: @bluewonder what do you mean by `position` do you want the index after which `/` it is coming ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one year value in your string, but you can do the following regex:

`[^\d](\d{5})[^\d]`

or simply

`\/(\d{5})\/`

or **very** specific to this case:

`codigoHotel\/(\d{5})\/zona`

and then get the first captured group which will be 2007

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/fU2bD5

Comment: Thanks @sshashank124 , but it is actually not a year, it is an ID in the URL

Comment: string value = Regex.Matches(url, @"http[s]?://www.testwebsite\.com/busqueda/(idPartner)/VINCCI/(codigoHotel)/(\d{4})/", RegexOptions.None)[0].Groups[1].Value;

Can I write one more specific Regex as above ? @sshashank124

Comment: @bluewonder, yeah definitely. whatever suits your needs/preferences. :)

Comment: @bluewonder, Remember, you might need to escape your `/` with a `\`

Comment: Thanks, but that example doesnt work for me, could you please have a check on that? Thanks @sshashank124

Comment: @bluewonder, The following works: `'https?:\/\/www.testwebsite.com\/busqueda\/\(idPartner\)\/VINCCI\/\(codigoHotel\)\/(\d{5})\/\(zona\)'`

Comment: Thanks; but when I run the regex in regex101 but show not match with the pattern

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to sshashank124's answer.

If you have the following url

```
   string url =  @"http://servername/username/collectionkey/sectionkey.extension";


//Using a Regex allows you to split the string, check that all required parts are there and check that the keys are numeric:

string servername = null, username = null, collectionkey = null, sectionkey = null;

Match m = Regex.Match(url, @"(?i:http://)(?<servername>[^\s/]*)/(?<username>[^\s/]*)/(?<collectionkey>\d*)(/(?<sectionkey>\d*))?(\.xml)?");
if (m.Success)
{
        servername = m.Groups["servername"].Value;
        username = m.Groups["username"].Value;
        collectionkey = m.Groups["collectionkey"].Value;
        sectionkey = m.Groups["sectionkey"].Value;
}
```